# .zshrc aliases not working with powerlevel10k

Tags: zsh

Running on `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`

I installed [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme) shell theme for zsh, but my aliases don't seem to work (e.g. `zsh: command not found: ll`) and I can't figure out why...

My .zshrc looks like this:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

source ~/shelltools/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
source ~/shelltools/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
source ~shelltools/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# git aliases
alias gca='git add .&&git commit -m '
alias gph='git push'
alias gpl='git pull'
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gcb='git checkout -b '
alias gcp='git checkout production'
alias gmp='git merge production'
alias gcd='git checkout develop'
alias gmd='git merge develop'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

The aliases are declared after the `source` lines, so I think they're not being overwritten..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us your operating system, you never know when that might be relevant; ii) add the contents (or a link to the contents, if it's too long) of this `~/shelltools/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme` you are sourcing; iii) tell us what actually happens when you try to run an alias. Nothing? Are there error messages?  What errors? iv) what happens if you define a new alias in the command line (e.g. `alias foo="echo foo"`) does that work?

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I edited my post. defining aliases on the command line works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused the problem in the end, but a reinstall of zsh and powerlevel10k theme ([manual installation](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#manual)) did the trick..